# eclipse maven dependencies moved under classpath after maven update project

Tags: eclipse, maven, java-module

In a maven project in eclipse version 2019-12, in "Java Build Path", I dragged "Maven Dependencies" from "Classpath" to "Modulepath".
But after clicked "Maven -> Update Project...", the "Maven Dependencies" is automatically moved under "Classpath" inside "Java Build Path".
Is it a normal behavior in eclipse? Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: I got an error in module-info.java saying "org.openqa.selenium.chrome cannot be resolved to a module". But the error gone when the "Maven Dependencies" (which contains some selenium jars) is under "Modulepath".

Comment: Has the corresponding dependency `<scope>test</scope>`? If yes, does removing `<scope>test</scope>` and _Maven > Update Project..._ fix your issue?

Comment: no <scope>test</scope> set

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the ***Maven Dependencies* item is always shown under *Classpath*** and moving to *Modulepath* has no effect.

This is a side effect of how classpath separation is implemented. If and only if there is a `module-info.java` file:

- **JARs to be used in `src/main/java` and `src/test/java`** (not only visible for test sources) are on the **modulepath**
- whereas **test scope JARs** (to be used in `src/test/java`) are on the **classpath**.

For projects without a `module-info.java` file, all dependencies are added to the classpath.